# What is the most common opposite word for "postpone"?

Tags: antonyms

Consider this:

> The meeting has been postponed.

How would the above example be said in AE or BE if the word "postponed" were to be replaced by its antonym?

Comment: "The meeting's been **moved/brought forward**" or "**anticipated**". But I suspect you're thinking of *prepone*, aren't you? :)

Comment: Is this a trick question? In ***Indian English*** there's no doubt that the answer here is ***prepone***. First recorded by the OED in 1917 (in New York), but it's never really caught on among "mainstream" Anglophones.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "opposite" and "antonym"? What *situation* do you want to describe? For example "the meeting has been brought forward" is commonly said in BrE but it isn't the opposite meaning, because a postponed meeting might not have a time/date, but be on hold. "Prepone" is not a commonly used term.

Comment: There is no antonym for postpone. There is only a starting point in time for an event after which, if schedule, it is said to be postponed.

Comment: @WeatherVane "Prepone" might be the word that describes what I meant by the antonym for "postpone". I was aiming to know that what native speakers of BE and AE call that word in their native languages, or what they use in place of "prepone".

Comment: @FumbleFingers It does answer my question. However, I was looking forward to knowing if both Brits and Americans use "brought forward" in place of "prepone". My above comment explains what I meant. :-)

Comment: As mentioned, in BrE "bring forward" is commonly used. I'm not sure many BrE speakers would understand "prepone".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes.

Comment: The earlier dup might be misleading in suggesting ***prepone*** is "an Indian word", given it was first recorded in New York. It's just that this "transparent neologism" only actually gained *traction* in IE. You might find some useful info in [Is “prepone” being used outside India?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/808/is-prepone-being-used-outside-india) (where somewhat fittingly, the syntax of the question title positively ***screams*** "Posted by speaker of Indian English" :)

Comment: ...I recall some debate not too long ago regarding *The meeting date has been **advanced** by a week*, which leaves many people uncertain whether it's been ***postponed** or ***preponed***.